# populating a text box with FindControl

Tags: c#, asp.net, findcontrol

I have multiple textboxes and I want to programatically populate them with the same method.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>    
    <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" DisplayAfter="500">
        <ProgressTemplate>
            <div id="FreezeUpdate" class="FreezePaneOn">
               <div id="InnerFreezePane" class="InnerFreezePane gradient"><asp:Literal ID="litProgress" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:LocalizedText, freezeMsg_ProcessingPleaseWait %>"></asp:Literal></style></div>
            </div>
        </ProgressTemplate>
    </asp:UpdateProgress>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <asp:TextBox ID="tbxCollectionAddress" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" ReadOnly="True" CssClass="address"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="tbxReturnAddress" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" ReadOnly="True" CssClass="address"></asp:TextBox>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

then the method...

```
protected void PopulateAddress(string txtTextbox, Address adrAddress)
    {
        TextBox txtAddress = (TextBox)FindControl(txtTextbox);

        txtAddress.Text = "Hello World";

    }
```

when I call this method like below...

```
PopulateAddress("tbxReturnAddress", CollectionAddress);
```

...I get exception...

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

...and it highlights the `txtAddress.Text = "Hello World";`  line.

I'd like to do it like this with the method because there are three separate addresses that I need to populate on the form but I'd like to try using re-usable code to do it by feeding in the address object and the textbox id, but I'm falling over just at the findcontrol stage.

What am I missing?

Comment: does this help:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y81z8326.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly , test your function likes

```
  TextBox txtAddress = (TextBox)FindControl("tbxReturnAddress");
```

**or**

You can try likes this ,

```
  TextBox txtAddress = (TextBox)Page.FindControl("tbxReturnAddress");
```

**Edit**

If your text-box is in the `UpdatePanel` ,

```
  TextBox txtAddress = (TextBox)UpdatePanel1.FindControl("tbxReturnAddress");
```

Comment: I get the same result :(

Comment: I've updated the question with the html part... Does it matter that the textbox exists within an update panel?

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks a lot! I didn't realise the update panel would affect the mapping like that. Learn something new everyday.
Thanks again! :)